# New line in emailBody not working in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have this code for showing some content in emailMessageBody. The code is given below.

```
var emailViewController : MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        emailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
        emailViewController.setToRecipients(["----"])
        emailViewController.setSubject("----")
        emailViewController.setMessageBody("\n\n\n" + "-- \r\n " + "----- Device : \(self.deviceName), App Version : \(self.appVersion), Model : \(deviceModel) , iOS Version : \(self.deviceVersion), Country Code : \(self.countryCode), Localised Model : \(deviceLocalizedModel) \n \n \n", isHTML: true)
        self.presentViewController(emailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You guys see that i put "\n" in the content, but its not showing new lines in the emailBody.
If anyone know how to get some new lines in emailMessageBody, Please help.

Comment: Use <\br>, because email body is in HTML format and in html you have to use <br> to break a line.

Comment: @Kampai Oh God. How could i forget about that.//

Comment: You need to add a tag `<br>` this. Not `\br`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `</br>` instead of `\n`

So your example code will look like the following

```
var emailViewController : MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    emailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
    emailViewController.setToRecipients(["----"])
    emailViewController.setSubject("----")
    emailViewController.setMessageBody("</br></br></br>" + "-- </br> " + "----- Device : \(self.deviceName), App Version : \(self.appVersion), Model : \(deviceModel) , iOS Version : \(self.deviceVersion), Country Code : \(self.countryCode), Localised Model : \(deviceLocalizedModel) </br></br></br>", isHTML: true)
    self.presentViewController(emailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `\n` you have to set the parameter `isHTML` to `false` in the `setMessageBody` call, otherwise you must use `</br>` instead of `\n` when you set the content for the message body.